# "US/Eastern" vs. "EST" time zone in Python

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

It is 2022/06/28 actually 28th of June 2022; I noticed when I try to get the current time from Python console two different results are possible the Eastern Time (Toronto, Montreal and New York). So what is the difference between these two parameters? I am going to answer the question:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way to get the current time in Toronto is:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
tz = timezone('EST')
print(datetime.now(tz))
```

The output is the following:

> 2022-06-28 16:23:23.333585-05:00

The second way to get the current time in Toronto is:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
print(datetime.now(tz))
```

The output is the following:

> 2022-06-28 17:24:42.944669-04:00

Conclusion:
If you use "EST" it is sometimes 1 hour ahead of the true time. I recommend you usually use ***'US/Eastern'***.

Comment: see [P. Eggert's tz database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/backward): "America/New_York" is actually the preferred way to specify US/Eastern time zone. And as a side note, you shouldn't use pytz anymore, we have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard library since Python 3.9

Answer (score 5):

"EST" is not accurate if you want to get the current time in New York because it represents Eastern Standard Time (UTC-05:00), which is one hour behind Eastern Daylight Time (UTC-04:00). Due to daylight savings, New York will observe either EST or EDT depending on the time of year.

"US/Eastern" is preferable to "EST" as it represents the Eastern Time Zone in the United States and will account for any shifts due to daylight savings. However, the zone representing "US/Eastern" has been [renamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to "America/New_York", and is maintained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'm surprised "EST" even works at all. 3 letter abbreviations aren't unique worldwide.

Comment: You're right about the abbreviations being ambiguous. It appears to be supported because the name appeared in previous versions of the time zone database