Pandas plot showing UTC instead of local time zone
Using the following code with all the appropriate libraries imported. This is for a daily log post I'm creating in my lifelog.
period = datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=1)
archive = zipfile.ZipFile("/Users/steven/Downloads/export.zip", "r")
df = pd.read_xml(
    archive.open("apple_health_export/export.xml"),
    xpath="//Record",
    attrs_only=True,
    parse_dates=["creationDate", "startDate", "endDate"],
)
d1 = df[
    (df["endDate"].dt.date == period)
    & (df["type"] == "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate")
]
d1["value"] = [pd.to_numeric(x) for x in d1["value"]]
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "PT Sans"
d1.sort_values(by="endDate").plot(
    x="endDate",
    y="value",
    xlabel="Time",
    ylabel="Heart Rate (BPM)",
    title="Heart Rate, Intraday",
).xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%-I:%M %p"))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(
    f"/Users/steven/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Web/gloriouslyawkwardlife.github.io/images/{period}-heartrateintraday.png",
    format="PNG",
)

The issue is that the plot is showing the times in the x-axis in UTC rather than EDT (GMT-4), even though the data coming in is also using EDT according to the sample below.
785810  HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRateVariabilitySDNN  Steven’s Apple Watch          11.1     ms  ... 2024-11-01 20:07:42-04:00 2024-11-01 20:08:42-04:00  67.3322  <<HKDevice: 0x30005b660>, name:Apple Watch, ma...
785811  HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRateVariabilitySDNN  Steven’s Apple Watch          11.1     ms  ... 2024-11-01 22:06:15-04:00 2024-11-01 22:07:15-04:00  26.4656  <<HKDevice: 0x30005b660>, name:Apple Watch, ma...
785812  HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRateVariabilitySDNN  Steven’s Apple Watch          11.1     ms  ... 2024-11-02 00:06:26-04:00 2024-11-02 00:07:25-04:00  197.345  <<HKDevice: 0x30005b660>, name:Apple Watch, ma...
785813  HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRateVariabilitySDNN  Steven’s Apple Watch          11.1     ms  ... 2024-11-02 02:07:08-04:00 2024-11-02 02:08:07-04:00  69.5713  <<HKDevice: 0x30005b660>, name:Apple Watch, ma...
785814  HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRateVariabilitySDNN  Steven’s Apple Watch          11.1     ms  ... 2024-11-02 04:06:10-04:00 2024-11-02 04:07:10-04:00  89.6994  <<HKDevice: 0x30005b660>, name:Apple Watch, ma...

Finished plot showing times in wrong time zone
I tried doing an explicit time zone conversion as follows but it doesn't affect the end result:
df['endDate']=df['endDate'].dt.tz_convert(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))

NOW, if I leave out the x-axis formatting (.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%-I:%M %p"))), the times shown in the chart are showing in the proper time zone, but not in the format I prefer. See this image.

Try setting matplotlib's default timezone or alternatively specifying tz=  when using DateFormatter(). For nicer formatting try mdates.ConciseDateFormatter().

If tz is not explicitly stated in mdates.DateFormatter("%-I:%M %p") it takes UTC. More about the EST/EDT timezone is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793634/26993270

You can use mdates.DateFormatter with the correct time zone by setting tz directly in the formatted.
Here's the code:
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%-I:%M %p", tz=pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
ax = d1.sort_values(by="endDate").plot(
    x="endDate",
    y="value",
    xlabel="Time",
    ylabel="Heart Rate (BPM)",
    title="Heart Rate, Intraday",
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

I hope this will help you a little.

pytz.timezone() may require using localize(). For python 3.9+, zoneinfo is a preferred option (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/26993270).

you could also just pass the string (tz identifier), docs
